# Possible to have association or not based on main model's data?

Tags: cakephp, database-design, associations, cakephp-2.1

I have a nodes table (`Node` model).  I'd like it to be associated to different data types, but only if one if it's field is set to `1`.

**Example:**

My `nodes` table has a `data_article` field (`tinyint 1`).  I only want the Node to `$hasMany Article` IF that field is a 1.

I tried this:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Article' => array(
        'conditions' => array('Node.data_articles' => '1')
    ),
);
```

But I get an error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Node.data_articles' in 'where
>   clause'

Because the association is doing the Article find in it's own query:

```
SELECT `Article`.`id`, `Article`.`title`, `Article`.`node_id`, ...more fields...
FROM `mydatabase`.`articles` AS `Article`
WHERE `Node`.`data_artiles` = '1'
AND `Article`.`node_id` = ('501991c2-ae30-404a-ae03-2ca44314735d')
```

Obviously that doesn't work, since the Node table isn't being Joined at all in this query.

**TLDR:**

Is it possible to have associations or not based on a field in the main model?  If not, how else can I keep different data types in multiple tables, and not have to query them all every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there's a standard way to do this with CakePHP (at least I can't imagine a way). What definitely is possible would be [binding associated models dynamically](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly).

So you might query your model without associations by passing the `recursive` parameter as `-1` to the `find()` method and based on the result [unbind](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelunbindModel) the associated models dynamically. Afterwards you would have to query again, for sure. You might build a [behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html) out of this to make it reusable.

A quite elegant solution would be possible, if Cake could make a two-step query with a [callback](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html) after the main model was queried, but before associated models are queried, but this isn't possible at the moment.

Edit: There might be a non-Cake way to archieve this more performantly with a custom Query including [IF-statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if), but I'm not the SQL expert here.

Comment: That works - thanks.  Probably better to perform the quick query if it reduces the main query by a 1-4 joins.

Answer (score -2):

You should do it from the other side:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
'Node' => array(
    'conditions' => array('Node.data_articles' => '1')
  ),
);
```

Comment: This does not work - The association(s) have to be on the model you're doing the find on.  If I only do the association this way, I cannot retrieve the extra data when I do a Node->find().  And it would not help to be forced to do the query from the actual data, as I wouldn't even know what data(s) to query.